# Insert text into Android webview

Tags: android

So I'm building an app that allows input from the user with their voice. I have built a webview and i have all the code to recieve voice input and transcode that into text. But now i want to be able to paste the text that the user says that i have already into whatever text box that is selected on the screen. For instance if the user is on google and clicked on the search box and says the words "stackoverflow", my app recieves the string containing "stackoverflow", now how do i paste that into the text box?

Thanks and let me know if i can give any further clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you knew exactly what page the user had opened and exactly what the ID of the element you wanted to populate was, there's no way to accomplish what you're describing (if I understand your request correctly).  Or are you asking how to populate an EditText that's in your Activity (I'm assuming that's NOT what you're asking, but just in case).

Comment: There would be no way to treat it as pasting text into the selected text box or something of that sort?

Comment: I want to make sure we're talking about the same thing. When all is said and done, you wish to paste a String that's in memory into an HTML Input that is on whatever web page the user happens to have loaded in the webView that you have provided for them?  If that is correct, then how do you know what field they have selected, and that they want to paste anything into it? Why not just let them paste manually? If the data is in memory, they should get the paste option in their options when they long hold the field.

Comment: Thats basically the idea. What i was hoping to do was have the user tap on the text box they want to type in and then instead of having to type just say the words "type stackoverflow" and i would paste "stackoverflow" into whatever textbox they already selected. So i guess my question would be if there is any way to figure out which text box is selected or to simply insert text into it.  Separately if i cant do that would there be any way to paste text into a textbox without the user doing the long hold?

Comment: I can't think of one, but really, if the user is aware of the fact that the string is now in memory, you can just Alert them to them reality that they should long hold a field.  I'll wait and see if anyone offers you any more *useful advice :)

Comment: I have seen an app where this is possible - RetailMeNot (only available in USA). You have to focus the input in the webview and then (short) tap on a textview of the app - then the text will appear in the webview. It works with any webpage. But I haven't discovered how this works yet.